# Security settings * differences between cmd.exe window and IE

Tags: security, ping, windows-command-prompt

I plan to retrieve an rss file (xml format) with url http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0 from a web site periodically with a scheduled task.  I have a php script to do that.  When I access the url in IE9 it shows the RSS.  When I load it with curl in the php script the request times out.  In fact when I ping the host `weather.gov` the request times out.  What about my settings could prevent access to that host from the cmd.exe window?  In other words is there something that I should do to be able to ping that host from cmd.exe?

Comment: Disable the proxy? Open the firewall for HTTP not only for the proxy? Give more information about your networks setup?!

Comment: @mailq The firewall is already open for HTTP.  The setup is just a verizon wireless router and a Windows Vista Business edition with IE9.

Comment: Try requesting the page with wget.exe in your command prompt.  It shows errors and such and should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @DougN wget.exe has old dlls.  Is there a different alternative to request the url?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing connectivity to the server manually:

```
> telnet alerts.weather.gov 80[enter]
[SCREEN TURNS BLANK]
GET /cap/ma.php?x=0 HTTP/1.0[enter][enter]
```

That should produce your output. If it doesn't, you have a connectivity problem and are probably using a proxy server in ie9. If it does work, something else is wrong.